# Como executar o webpack + ReactJS sem node.js no client-side?

Tags: webpack, babel, react

É possível rodar o transpilador do webpack no client-side sem a instalação e execução do mesmo em um servidor Node.js ?

Atualmente estou tentando implementar uma aplicação SPA utilizando React 15.1.0 integrado com o Babel-core 5.8.23 . Porém minha solução server-side é proprietária e não tenho possibilidade de altera-la devido ao suporte de atualizações, sendo a mesma contem uma integração entre serviços e aplicações muito complexa, onde até mesmo existe um serviço Node.js próprio pra ela.

Qual caminho ou configurações posso seguir para rodar o React desenvolvido somente no lado front-end com execução também somente no client-side.

**OBS:** atualmente meu principal entrave está sendo a importação de componentes modularizados que apresenta o erro .. `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` .

Códigos de Teste:

**index.html**  e   **main.js**

```js
// Arquivo "main.js"

import App from './components/App.js';

ReactDOM.render(
 <App />,
 document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Aprendendo React</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Testes com código ReactJS">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/babel" src="main.js" ></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="app"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render: function() {
        return <h1>React Ok</h1>;
    }
});
```

Comment: Porque não fazes um projeto à parte e este código como micro-serviço? Assim podes compilar o ficheiro js separado do teu outro projeto.

Comment: Eu estou extremamente limitado pois para acessar minha base de dados eu preciso deixar o código integrado ao meu server-side que atualmente usa o **Freemaker** para criar a camada MVC compilada emJava que interpreta o código e inclui objetos no JS.. porém também estava pensando nessa solução onde teria em outro servidor Node o webpack, mas ainda não entendi como conseguiria fazer funcionar.

Comment: Não podes criar um end-point no teu servidor actual para o novo serviço só comunicar por ajax? assim crias um novo projeto e compilas com Node, mas corre tudo no browser e só fala com o servidor via ajax.

Comment: @Sergio  eu já tenho essa funcionalidade de acesso do servidor via REST API com autenticação OAuth, mas como eu poderia rodar/configurar esse projeto Node.js em um segundo servidor para processamento das páginas? você tem alguma referência disso?

Comment: Podes explicar o que queres dizer por "processamento das páginas"? referes-te a compilar com webpack?